# Accesing Excel Table (ListObject) by Linq

Tags: linq, excel, vsto, listobject

I need to create a table in Excel (programatically) and then access the `ListObject` that the table is based on by Linq. It must be done as fast as possible. I have dug through tons of examples and I cannot find a solution that satisfies me. Most Linq queries to Excel data require openXML and acces to the whole file. I need to do this in application-level addin with acces to specific worksheet.

I also thought of binding `ListObject` to data table and then use Linq. But I cannot bind `DataTable` to `ListObject` that alredy exist (the data table would erase the data in `ListObject`)

Has anyone tried this before ?

Comment: i have not worked with LINQ, but give this a thought: you can access Excel data via normal database connectivity (google for excel connection strings). you can either refer to a full sheet as a table - or to a named range. unfortunately not to a table range directly. however, if you save a named range in your excel that is exactly as the table (but does not use the table notation, but the normal A1 references), the range will automatically adjust as the table grows - so you can access it externally... HTH!

Comment: After reconsidering my needs I decided that for a table that I reguire (in 99/100 cases it will have less than 500 entries) it will be better to copy the content od the table to list of type that matched the table entry and then use linq on a list.It is ok as the table content changes in on specyfic ocasion and it is not cibtrolled by user directly